# Pass JavaScript variable to JSP session

Tags: javascript, jsp

I wrote a code to get client ip address from JavaScript. But i can't get proper output from that. i am getting error in this semicolon `<% ; %>`. I mentioned my code below. thank you.

```
<script>
function getMyIpAddress() {
$.getJSON("https://jsonip.com?callback=?", function(data) {
    <%String ipAddress =%>data.ip; <% ; %>
    //alert("Your IP address is :- " + data.ip);
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ipAddress;
    <% session.setAttribute("clientipAddress", ipAddress); %>
   });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jsp is **java servlet page**.So in the `<% %>` or `<% =%>` should be **java** fragment code.
As you see,In you code `<%String ipAddress =%>` there just a **variable declaration** the ipAddress is null, the correct grammar is `<%ipAddress=%>`,and the `<% ; %>` is wrong grammar in java too.

Comment: thank you for your answer and can i correct this if i use `<%ipAddress=%>` and `<%;%>`

Comment: I think the logic is entire wrong, you can not evaluate the java variable in js. That is irreversible. The server side evaluate java and the browser run js.

Comment: how can i solve this?? is there any solution with u for this??